# Facebook Requests into a Facebook Page Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone know if Facebook Requests can be made to redirect into a Facebook Page app rather than into the Canvas app?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not redirect to any just url you give it. You should have them redirect from the Canvas app to the Facebook Page. Although that will be ugly/poor user experience. That's your only option.